# Django: FileField' object has no attribute 'attrs' in class Meta

Tags: python-3.x, django

I have a simple problem. Inside a modelForm, in my Meta class, inside `widgets={}` i have specified:

```
'video' : forms.FileField(allow_empty_file=True)
```

however django complains that `'FileField' object has no attribute 'attrs'`. What could be the issue

Comment: A `FileField` is *not* a widget. It is a form *field*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A [**`FileField`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/forms/fields/#filefield) is a *form field*, not a widget*. The default widget of a `FileField` is a [**`ClearableFileInput`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/forms/widgets/#clearablefileinput).

You can thus construct a (model)form with:

```
class MyForm(forms.Form):
    video = forms.FileField(allow_empty_file=True)

    # …
```